# Character position number in string

Tags: sql

Try to get from the value - "some kind of tex @123fpe2"
all characters ​​after the @ sign
Prepared the code below
but the problem is that not always the length of the value after the sign @ 8 characters

```
select REVERSE(Left(Reverse(vValue), 8)),
(
select vValue from Runtime.dbo.Live where TagName = 'CurrentBaseRecipeName32000000io') as ValueForCheck,

from Runtime.dbo.Live where TagName = 'CurrentBaseRecipeName32000000io'
```

Getting error:

```
select REVERSE(Left(Reverse(vValue), POSITION('@' IN vValue))),
(
select vValue ...

select REVERSE(Left(Reverse(vValue), 8)),
(
select vValue from Runtime.dbo.Live where TagName = 'CurrentBaseRecipeName32000000io') as ValueForCheck,

from Runtime.dbo.Live where TagName = 'CurrentBaseRecipeName32000000io'
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is MySQL because of the use of POSITION in the question. Use INSTR to get the position of the '@' and then SUBSTRING to return everything after the index returned by INSTR + 1

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(vValue, INSTR(vValue, '@') + 1) FROM Runtime.dbo.Live
WHERE ...
```

Just in case, here is a version for SQL Server using RIGHT

```
SELECT RIGHT(vValue,  LEN(vValue) - CHARINDEX('@', vValue)) FROM Runtime.dbo.Live
WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that there is only 1 `@` in the string, or if there are more than 1 and you want the part of the string after the last occurrence of `@`, then you can use [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('some kind of tex @123fpe2', '@', -1);
```

will return:

```
123fpe2
```